# total video count via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How to get the total video count using the Facebook Graph API in a faster way. It gives videos with limit count and next page id. When i reduce limit count, it works very slowly but when decrease limit, return error "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request". How can i get video total count faster?

```
$InsightsPageVideos = "https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{$business_id}/videos?fields=data&limit=7000&access_token=" . $business_access_token;
```

this return

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": {video id}
    }
  ],
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{page_id}/videos?access_token={token}"
```

I loop on next and plus data count

```
$GetPageVideos= Http::get($InsightsPageVideos);
$data = $response['data'];
$next_page = $GetPageVideos->json()['paging']['next'] ?? null;
$video_count = count($response_data);
while ($next_page) {
   $response = Http::withHeaders([
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$business_access_token,
                     'fields' => 'data'
               ])->get($next_page);
   $response_data[] = $response->json()['data'];
   $video_count += count($response_data);
   $next_page = $response->json()['paging']['next'] ?? null;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what field `data` is supposed to be, I don't find that in the documentation for the Video object type. Maybe just directly ask for only `id` instead, and see if that changes anything regarding the amount-of-data error?